# How would I add a <u> tag to an html inline angular variable that is the result of a ternary expression?

Tags: html, angularjs

So I've got the following going on right now.

```
<label>
    Make {{$ctrl.tcTemplate.isLibrary ? $ctrl.tcTemplate.name : "this item"}} a Library item:
    <toggle ng-change="changed(); $ctrl.eraseName();" ng-model="$ctrl.tcTemplate.isLibrary;" off="False" on="True" type="checkbox"></toggle>
</label>
```

What happens basically is you flip a switch to "true" and I want the label to display dynamically the name of the item which you can type in if the switch is "true" so it would read

Make {{ctrl.tcTemplate.name}} a library item: true.

If the switch is "false" the item doesn't get a name, so I want the label to just display,

Make "this item" a Library item: False

So I've got my ternary statement set up to check if the switch is true or false, and if true display my variable, if false display the string, "this item"

If the switch is true, and the variable value is displayed, I was trying to make it underlined.

So here were 4 variants I tried.

```
{{$ctrl.tcTemplate.isLibrary ? <u>$ctrl.tcTemplate.name</u> : "this item"}}
{{$ctrl.tcTemplate.isLibrary ? '<u>' + $ctrl.tcTemplate.name + '</u>' : "this item"}}
{{$ctrl.tcTemplate.isLibrary ? <u>{{$ctrl.tcTemplate.name}}</u> : "this item"}}
{{$ctrl.tcTemplate.isLibrary ? <u>{{$ctrl.tcTemplate.name}\}</u> : "this item"}}
```

The first one just turns the entire ternary expression into a string, and the whole line is displayed in my label

second one returns {{$ctrl.tcTemplate.isLibrary ? '' + $ctrl.tcTemplate.name + '' : "this item"}} as an entire string literal and the contents from empty quotes to empty quotes is underlined.

Three and four, I don't really know what I was thinking, or doing, I was just messing around and thought the failed attempts were worth mentioning. They were returned as string literals as well minus the use of the escape character in attempt four.

So any ideas on how I can get just that variable to display underlined when the ternary statement equates to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use a ternary statement. Use ng-if, or ng-show, or ng-switch instead:

```
Make <u ng-if="$ctrl.tcTemplate.isLibrary">{{ $ctrl.tcTemplate.name }}</u> 
     <span ng-if="!$ctrl.tcTemplate.isLibrary">this item</span>
  a Library item:
```

Comment: Oh man that seems so obvious after having read it. It totally work, I can't believe I couldn't come to this conclusion on my own. I think tunnel vision got the best of me. Thanks so much for the help, man!